# How to add html li control dynamically in repeater

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to add new `li` after three `Repeater1_ItemDataBound` in asp.net, and my html code is

```
 <asp:repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <ul class="slider carousel" id="sliderName">
          <li class="slide">
             <div class="one-third column alpha portfolio-item">
                <div  class="content">
                   <div class="border">
                      <asp:Image ID="imgHotels" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="130px" class="scale-with-grid" />
                      <a href="" class="prettyPhoto zoom"></a>
                      <a class="link" href=""></a>
                   </div>
                   <center><h5 class="noline"><a href="#">

                   <asp:Label Visible ="false" ID="lblhotelid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SrNo") %>'></asp:Label>      
                   <asp:Label ID="lblhotelname" Visible="true" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("hotelname") %>'></asp:Label>

                   </a></h5></center> <div class="shadow">
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </li>   
      </ul>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

and how can I add html control `li` in this code?

```
        if (repeat % 3 == 0)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl();//create the html control li
}
```

thanks, for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating html controls in the code-behind is a bad practice.

try this one:

```
<li runat="server" Id="liControl" Visible='<%# Container.ItemIndex % 3 == 0 ? "true" : "false" %>' >...</li>
```

or

```
<% if(Container.ItemIndex % 3 == 0) { %>
    <li>...</li>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a literal where you want to insert extral li in repeater item template

find the same in row databound and assign the data to the text property
some thing like below.

```
if (repeat % 3 == 0)
    {
        Literal ltrlLiContent=(Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lstrLiContent");

        string strDataForli="";  //fill your content with li tags into this variable

        ltrlLiContent.Text=strDataForli;
    }
```